# Port Forwarding новые фичи в VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

В vs code появился port forwarding. Не понял как с ним работать. Есть проект на Flask. В VS Code открываю папку с этим проектом. Далее в ports создаю новый порт, например 3000. Только при переходе по ссылке которая потом там выдается, HTTP Error 502 - страница не доступна.

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашёл. Flask проект запускается если прописать app.run(). Для функции run(), параметру port нужно передать тот самый порт